# Need help in spilt agrs discord js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

This is my embed code,  How can make embed command, like the text before a special symbol (say | ) is title and after symbol its description? I need help with this thank you

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: "embed",
    description: "make embed",

    async run(Client, message,  args){
        if(!message.member.hasPermission('MANNAGE_MESSAGES')) return // if the member does not have permissions to mannage messages, return/stop reading the code.
        let color = args[0]
        let title = `__**${args[1]} ${args[2]}**__` 
        let description = args.slice(3).join(" ") // args.slice(3).join(" ") means we're taking all the arguments including and after the second argument. An argument is just a word or number.
        const error = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setTitle('**❌ERROR INVALID ARGS**')
        .setDescription("-embed title(2 words) color[hex code or basic colors in caps; i.e(YELLOW)] description(embed body)")

        if(!title) return message.channel.send(error) // ! means no, so if there's no title, return and send the error embed
        if(!color) return message.channel.send(error)
        if(!description) return message.channel.send(error)

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(title)
        .setColor(color)
        .setDescription(description)
        .setFooter(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL())
        message.delete() // this deletes the command

        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `args.split("|")` here.

Comment: 1. You're clearly getting some array in `args`. Can you please describe what you're expecting in that array?
2. `args.slice(3)` will take all the elements of the `args` array after the third argument. So, the comment describing `args.slice(3).join(" ")` is wrong. Can you please reiterate what you want to do with the rest of the arguments (after third element of `args`)?